# Fruit internal defect detection using image processing

Tags: image, processing

I have to find internal fruit defect of mango by finding the seed area of the mango by drawing a circle on the outer boundary of the mango image and the calculating the centroid and then drawing one more circle near seed area and then finding it's centroid also after that find histogram and intensity.

I have made two contours but my mentor asked me to make circle and then find out the centroid and histogram